# Why I can't get param from my table?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7

I have tabel: `tags(id,name,created_at, updated_ad)`

I have model:

tag

```
class Tag extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];

    protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
    ];
    public function Posts()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Post::class, 'taggable');
    }
}
```

I have tag controller:

```
class TagController extends Controller
{
    public function show(Tag $Tag)
    {
        return Response::json($Tag);
    }
}
```

I have routs:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Tags', 'prefix' => 'tags'], function () {
        Route::get('/{tags}', 'TagController@show');
        Route::delete('/{tags}', 'TagController@destroy')->middleware('auth:api');
    });
```

I try to get tag with id, but it don't work. What i do wrong or what of forget  define?

Comment: Did you add the route-model binding for "tags"? See https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-model-binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controller should like something like that:

```
use App\Tag;

class TagController extends Controller
{
    public function show($tag)
    {
        return Response::json(Tag::find($tag));
    }
}
```

routes:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'tags', 'prefix' => 'tags'], function () {
        Route::get('/{tag}', 'TagController@show');
        Route::delete('/{tag}', 'TagController@destroy')->middleware('auth:api');
    });
```

Comment: ReflectionException
Class App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController does not exist

Comment: Route::group(['namespace' => 'tags', 'prefix' => 'tags'], function () { - "tags" must be "Tags"